# How to use gettext?

Tags: gettext

I am trying to understand how to use gettext. The following work flow does not retrieve the French text correctly. How can I get it to work?

```
$ cat po/fr/hello.po
msgid "Hello World\n"
msgstr "Bonjour le monde\n"
$ msgfmt -o po/fr/hello.mo po/fr/hello.po
$ cp po/fr/hello.mo fr/LC_MESSAGES/hello.mo
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define _(STRING) gettext(STRING)

int main() {
  /* Setting the i18n environment */
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  bindtextdomain ("hello", "/usr/share/locale/");
  textdomain ("hello");

  /* Example of i18n usage */
  printf(_("Hello World\n"));

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
$ gcc -o hello.exe hello.c
$ LANG=fr_FR ./hello.exe
Hello World
```

Comment: Check the return value of `setlocale()` to see whether the French locale is available. And does the directory `/usr/share/locale` really exist and is the `.mo` file installed there?

Comment: I see some `.mo` files `$ find /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES -name '*.mo' | head -n 1
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/tasksel.mo`. How to check what msgid are defined in it?

Comment: Try `msgunfmt FILE.mo`.